# Step in proof Euler Phi function of Divisors (part 3)

Tags: group-theory

Consider the following bi-implications:
$$
\operatorname{ord}(\overline a)=d\iff \gcd(a,n)=\frac{n}{d}\iff a=b\cdot\frac{n}{d}\text{, where $\gcd(b,d)=1$ and $1\leq b\leq d$}.
$$
I am able to show the first two bi-implications, and the last $\implies$. I still have difficulty showing the last $\impliedby$. So say $a=b\cdot\dfrac{n}{d}$, with $\gcd(b,d)=1$ and $1\leq b\leq d$. I'm guessing that if $\gcd(b,d)>1$, then we would get a contradiction with $\gcd(a,b)=\dfrac{n}{d}$, but I don't know how to get that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Write $n=xy$ with $x$ maximal integer such that $\gcd(x,d)=1$. In particular, $d$ divides $y$. Then
\begin{align}
\gcd(a,n)&=\gcd\left(bx\frac{y}{d}, xy\right)=x\gcd\left(b\frac{y}{d}, y\right)\\
&=x\gcd\left(b\frac{y}{d}, d\frac{y}{d}\right)=x \frac{y}{d}\gcd\left(b, d\right)=\frac{n}{d}.
\end{align}